# How to write the path of a 32 bit executable in the Windows' Program Files folder regardless of the Windows version?

Tags: windows

I want to write something like

%ProgramFiles(x86)%\someprogram\someprogram.exe

That would work in both Windows 32 and 64-bit versions

But:

1. `%ProgramFiles%` points to the 32 bit program files folder only in 32bit Windows
2. `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` points to the 32 bit program files folder only in 64bit Windows (it doesn't exist in 32-bit Windows)

Is there any Windows Environment variable that always point to the 32 bit program files folder, regardless of the Windows version?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017468/what-unique-environment-variable-can-i-use-to-get-the-32-bit-program-files-folde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` to the 32bit Windows platforms.  You can use a simple command line to add it:

`Set ProgramFiles(x86) = "C:\Program Files"`

Then you have consistency across platforms.

Edit:

Since you told me what it is for, I would do something like this for your instructions:

```
1 - Change to the directory for the program. 

2 - open a command prompt 

3a - type "cd %programfiles(x86)%" 

3b - If  you receive the error "The system cannot find the path specified", 
     go to step 3c.  Otherwise go to 4. 

3c - type "cd %programfiles%" 

4 - Other stuff
```

Comment: You're right, but I need a solution that would work out of the box.

Comment: What are you using this for?  I ask because if you are writing a script or installer, or a batch file, it is trivial to add this variable: `IF %ProgramFiles(x86) == "" SET ProgramFiles(x86) = "C:\Program Files"`

Comment: I'm putting this path in the web as instructions to a not-so-smart audience

Comment: In that case, I would say make it a 2-part step.  See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution is:

```
  if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" (
    echo Win x86
    set PRGFILES=%ProgramFiles%
  ) else (
    echo Win x64
    set PRGFILES=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
  )
  echo 1: %PRGFILES%
```

The above solution caused some problems on first testing. It seemed like the ")" character in %ProgramFiles(x86)% caused end of if. Therefore secondary solution:

```
  if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" set PRGFILES=%ProgramFiles%
  if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" set PRGFILES=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
  echo 2: %PRGFILES%
```

Tested only on Win 7 x64 and Win XP (x86).

According to my test it is better to use custom temporary environment variable and do not use direct the program files variables (above mentioned problems).